Manga where the main character has amnesia and a magical ability
It starts with him having amnesia and realising he has a magical power, then he whenever he meets others with different magical powers, they all try to kill him. It's a fairly old manga, never read more than 6 chapters tops. I believe the main character had fire and the first person that tried to kill him could control spatial dimensions to lock someone out of the real world (basically locking someone inside a "cube").

In roughly which year did you read this? Was it full colour or mostly black & white? And did it take place in a modern/realistic setting or a historical/fantasy setting?

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

i dont know what manga you are looking for, but it reminds me of the story of THE HIGHLANDER , which has a few films and tv series and books. immortals who can sense each other and kill each other to become more powerful.
